# Service not running: app closed and smartphone screen off

Tags: android

I made an application with: an activity (MainActivity) that starts a service (SmartphoneListener).

Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,SmartphoneListener.class);
    startService(intent);
}
}
```

The service is used to detect (on smartphone) if the connection with smartwatch is lost.

Service

```
public class SmartphoneListener extends WearableListenerService {

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,"MyWakelockTag"); //Service running even if the screen is off.
    wakeLock.acquire();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onPeerDisconnected(Node node){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Communication with smartwatch lost",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    registerReceiver(mIntentReceiver, filter);
}

private BroadcastReceiver mIntentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //
    }
};
...
}
```

If my application is open and the smartphone screen is off I can detect if I lost my connection with smartwatch (the mIntentReceiver code is executed).
Then If I close my application and the smartphone screen is off I can't detect if I lost my connection with smartwatch (the mIntentReceiver code is not executed).
I don't know why.

Comment: How are you "closing" your app: backing out, pressing Home button, swiping it from recent task list?

Comment: Swiping it from recent task list.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
```

to your IntentFilter. Hope it help!

Answer (score 0):

You explained in the reply to my comment that you are "closing" the app by swiping it from the recent tasks list.  This action causes the process for your app to be killed.  Because you return `START_STICKY` from `onStartCommand()` in your service, the system will create a new instance of your app in a new process and call `onStartCommand()` to restart your service.  That is the only entry made into your app.  No activities are recreated.  I know very little about Wear. I'm guessing that your app performs some configuration processing to locate and connect to nodes.  If that processing is done in some activity, such as your launch activity, it will not be performed when your app is recreated to restart your service.